# Error message when reading org file containing bibtex block

Tags: org-mode, bibtex

I have an org file containing bibtex source blocks. Some time
after I open it, I get the message

```
    Error running timer `bibtex-parse-buffers-stealthily':
    (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
```

How do I proceed in order to stop getting this message?

Comment: I would cancel the timer (`M-x list-timers` and `c` on the relevant timer), then make sure that `debug-on-error` is set, and then run `bibtex-parse-buffers-stealthily` by hand and look at the backtrace. If that is not enough to pinpoint the error, I would try to run it in a debugger. The goal is to find where in the bibtex files the error arose and fix it there. The backtrace (and/or the debugging run) might point to some entry in  a bibtex  file that is close to where the problem arises and maybe by staring at the file a bit you might see the problem.

Comment: If you can find an approximate location, you can then try it on a trimmed bibtex file which might make the debugging easier.